# Can't move buttons to the right side

Tags: html, css

I have problem where I can't move objects in div (buttons in this case) to one side.

I have this `HTML`:

```html
      <div class='post-div'>
        <h1>There will be title</h1>
        <div class='post-content-and-actions'>
          <div class='peace-of-content'>
            <p>Here will be a little bit of content and Lorem ipsum</p>
          </div>
          <div class='actions'>
            <button class='edit'>EDIT</button>
            <button class='edit delete'>DELETE</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And `css`:

```css
.post-div {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 8px;
  .post-content-and-actions {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    .peace-of-content {
      width: 700px;
    }
    .actions {
      width: 300px;
      .edit {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: green;
        &.delete {
          background-color: red;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In `actions` section I want to move all buttons to the right and whatever I do, I just can't. `float: right`, `right: 0` etc. Actually, I have no idea why!

Comment: make .actions a flex container and justify-content:flex-start; or just display:inline-block (.edit)

Comment: you needed to add ```.post-content-and-actions { justify-content:s pace-between;}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `text-align: right;` to `.actions` :

```css
    ...
    .actions {
      width: 300px;
      text-align: right;
      ...
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but with `text-align: right`, not `end`, thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer, I didn't check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#browser_compatibility) for `start` and `end` values.

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox will easily achieve this..

```css
.actions {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 300px;
    .edit {
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
```